# Computing inverse kinetic operator for in-in formalism

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, correlation-functions, greens-functions, propagator

Consider the kinetic operator in in-in formalism.

\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{2} \int_{x, y} \phi^{A}_{x} K^{AB}_{x, y} \phi^{B}_{y}
\end{align}
where $K^{AB}$ is the kinetic operator with the form
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  K^{AB}_{x,y} = \begin{pmatrix} K^{++}_{x,y} & 0 \\ 0 & K^{--}_{x,y} \end{pmatrix}
  =\begin{pmatrix}
    (-\square_y +m^2) \delta^{4}(x-y) & 0 \\
    0 & -(-\square_y +m^2) \delta^{4}(x-y)
  \end{pmatrix}\,,
\end{aligned}
\label{}
\end{equation}
with $A = (+,-)$ [In some references they used $R$ and $L$]

I want to compute the inverse kinetic operator $G$ out of $K$. i.e.,
\begin{align}
 \int_{y} K_{xy}^{AB} G^{AB}_{yz} =\begin{pmatrix}
      \delta^{4}(x-z) & 0 \\
      0 & \delta^{4}(x-z)
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

The known results from the references state as following:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  G^{AB}_{x,y} = \begin{pmatrix} G^{++}_{x,y} & G^{+-}_{x,y} \\ G^{-+}_{x,y} & G^{--}_{x,y} \end{pmatrix}\,,
\end{aligned}
\label{}
\end{equation}
and explicitly
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  G^{++}_{x,y} &= \int_{p} \frac{e^{i p\cdot (x-y)}}{p^{2}+m^{2} -i\epsilon}\,,
  \\
  G^{+-}_{x,y} &= \int_{p} e^{i p\cdot (x-y)} 2\pi i \delta(p^{2}+m^{2}) \Theta(p^{0})\,,
  \\
  G^{-+}_{x,y} &= \int_{p} e^{i p\cdot (x-y)}2\pi i \delta(p^{2}+m^{2}) \Theta(-p^{0})\,,
  \\
  G^{--}_{x,y} &= -\int_{p} \frac{e^{i p\cdot (x-y)}}{p^{2}+m^{2} + i\epsilon}\,,
\end{aligned}\label{}
\end{equation}
with $\int_{p} = \int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4} $.

---

My question is how to obtain $G^{+-}, G^{-+}$ from the inverse relation.

For the $G^{++}$ and $G^{--}$ parts from $K^{++}$ and $K^{--}$ so it is okay, but I have trouble understanding the form of $G^{+-}$ and $G^{-+}$.

Comment: Hi @phy_math. Are you following a reference for notation & conventions?

Comment: Also, what should $A$ and $B$ stand for? Are they supposed to be summed over? Clearly the inverse of a diagonal matrix is diagonal so there must be something else going on ..